# Lessico aulico per gruppi in quantità definita

Tags: word-choice, etymology

Vorrei completare il seguente elenco di termini atti a designare gruppi (solitamente gruppi di divinità, o di opere) in quantità definita:

1. Monade
2. Dìade
3. Trìade
4. Tètrade
5. Pèntade
6. **?** (Èsade?)
7. **?** (Èttade, èptade?)
8. Ogdòade
9. Ennèade
10. Dècade

I termini *tetrade* e *pentade* sono usati nel linguaggio musicale, ma non ho trovato occorrenze corrispondenti ai numeri sei e sette. Mi lascia perplesso il fatto che *ogdoade* non segua la dizione dotta che mi aspetterei (*octade*), né quella popolare (*ottade*), quindi non saprei dare un'indicazione precisa sul numero sette in particolare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nella voce dell'Enciclopedia Italiana (1930) [sull'eresiarca gnostico Basilide](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/basilide_%28Enciclopedia-Italiana%29/) sono usati sia “**esade**” che “**eptade**”, oltre che “ogdoade”, per la descrizione del sistema concepito appunto da Basilide:

> ...dalla terza figliolanza deriva un primo ἄρχων, con un figlio, sua mente, e un'esade per completare l'ogdoade, infine un sistema di 365 cieli (Abraxas) fino al cielo della luna; sotto il cielo della luna un'eptade con un minore ἄρχων creatore del mondo materiale.

In effetti sembra che siano termini molto rari; non li trovo a lemma – né cercando a tutto testo, con questa unica eccezione – in nessuno dei maggiori dizionari/enciclopedie: Treccani, Zingarelli, De Mauro, Battaglia.

Quest'ultimo registra però, a differenza degli altri, [“ogdoade”](https://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/11?seq=851) e ci fa notare che la peculiarità della formazione viene dal fatto che il termine deriva dall'ordinale ὄγδοος (ógdoos), “ottavo”, piuttosto che dal cardinale ὀκτώ (octó), come in “ottagono” etc. Da questo punto di vista, la parola “ogdoade” è imparentata quindi con [“ebdomada”](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ebdomada) (da ἕβδομος, hébdomos, “settimo”), termine ricercato per indicare la settimana.

Per inciso, anche varie parole con radici latine usano il tema dell'ordinale (“terzina”, “quartina”, “sestina”, e anche la stessa “settimana”).

<sub>EDIT: Attenzione, sul Treccani è sbagliato lo spirito su ἕβδομος, che è aspro, come scrivo qui, e non dolce come risulta lì.</sub>

Comment: Grazie molte per la risposta davvero esaustiva e di aver scritto l'etimologia esatta di *ogdoade*!

Comment: Grazie a te! La tua domanda mi ha interessato alla questione e mi ha fatto venire voglia di approfondire.